# How to show a null-set is a $\sigma$-algebra if and only if $\mu(\Omega)=0$?

Tags: measure-theory

I am having a bit of trouble with my assigment on Measures and Integrals. First I have been giving the measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ and the $\mu$-null set (or empty-set):
$\mathcal{N}_\mu=\{N\subseteq \Omega| \quad \exists A \in \mathcal{A}: N \subseteq A \text{ and } \mu(A)=0\}$.
I have proved the following properties: 
$\emptyset \in \mathcal{N}_\mu$ and
If $N_n\in \mathcal{N}_\mu, \quad n=1,2,... ,$ then $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty N_n \in \mathcal{N}_\mu$.
The last thing I need to show is that:
$\mathcal{N}_\mu$ is a $\sigma$-algebra if and only if $\mu(\Omega)=0$.
Maybe some of you guys can give me a hint on what to do, to get started on the proof? Thank you.

Comment: If $\mathcal{N} _{\mu} $ is a sigma algebra then it must be closed under complementation. Why does this mean that we must have $\mu (\Omega) =0 $?

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathcal{N}_{\mu}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra then $\Omega$ is $\mathcal{N}_{\mu}$. By definition of $\sigma$-algebra there is some $A \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\Omega \subseteq A$ and $\mu(A)=0$. In order for $\Omega \subseteq A$ to hold we must have $A = \Omega$. Hence $\mu(\Omega)=0$.

Suppose now $\mu(\Omega)=0$. The only things that you still needs to prove in order to show $\mathcal{N}_{\mu}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra is that $\Omega \in \mathcal{N}_{\mu}$ and that $\mathcal{N}_{\mu}$ is closed under complementation. Since you already noticed that $\emptyset \in \mathcal{N}_{\mu}$ we just need to prove the second property. Let $N \in \mathcal{N}_{\mu}$. Choose $A=\Omega \in \mathcal{A}$ (this is possible because $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra). Then $\Omega \setminus N \subseteq \Omega=A$ and $\mu(A)=\mu(\Omega)=0$. Hence $\Omega \setminus N \in \mathcal{N}_{\mu}$ and $\mathcal{N}_{\mu}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.